# Ajax from Python, without using libraries

Tags: ajax, python-3.x

Ajax from Python, without using libraries - how do I do it?

How would I update something at `http://localhost/update.php?text=Hello world`?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755507/creating-a-raw-http-request-with-sockets) is helpful, but what about the Ajax parameters to the URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a raw HTTP request with sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755507/creating-a-raw-http-request-with-sockets)

Comment: But what about the Ajax part? The  parameters to the URL?

Comment: As usual, the cowardly downvote gvies no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @unwind's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506379/add-params-to-given-url-in-python):

> use [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html).
>
> From the [examples](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#examples) in the documentation:
>
> ```
> >>> import urllib
> >>> params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
> >>> f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.musi-cal.com/cgi-bin/query?%s" % params)
> >>> print f.geturl() # Prints the final URL with parameters.
> >>> print f.read() # Prints the contents
> ```