# Make full HTTP request using single string

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I am trying to make little automated-testing script. It shoud be able to make HTTP request based on string provided, something like follows:

```
import coollib  # non-existent library

r = coollib.make_raw_request(
    # Lets assume, python's tripple quoted string spacing is not a problem.
    """
        GET / HTTP/1.1\n\r
        Host: example.com\n\r
        My-Faulty-Header: status\n\r
    """
)

print(r.response_body)
```

Intention behind this is to insert a little mistakes into request, to test, how web server copes with faulty requests.

Any idea how to do this? Any insights are welcome.

Comment: I know nothing about `coollib`. But you might look into the `socket` module. That's a start, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ronald Aaronson mentioned in the comment, your weapon of choice here should probably be the [socket](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/socket.html) library. There's an example in this related question: [Creating a raw HTTP request with sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755507/creating-a-raw-http-request-with-sockets)