# Process raw HTTP request to python requests

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to pass a raw HTTP request like:

```
GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; fr; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://example.org/test
Cookie: foo=bar; lorem=ipsum;
```

And generate the python request such as:

```
import requests

burp0_url = "http://example.org:80/foo/bar"
burp0_cookies = {"foo": "bar", "lorem": "ipsum"}
burp0_headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; fr; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8", "Accept": "*/*", "Accept-Language": "fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate", "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", "Keep-Alive": "115", "Connection": "keep-alive", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", "Referer": "http://example.org/test"}
requests.get(burp0_url, headers=burp0_headers, cookies=burp0_cookies)
```

Is there a library for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a raw HTTP request with sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755507/creating-a-raw-http-request-with-sockets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find an existing library that does this conversion, but there is a Python library to convert `curl` commands to python requests code.
https://github.com/spulec/uncurl

e.g.

```
import uncurl
print(uncurl.parse('curl --header "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" --compressed --header "Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3" --header "Connection: keep-alive" --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --cookie "foo=bar; lorem=ipsum;" --header "Keep-Alive: 115" --header "Referer: http://example.org/test" --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; fr; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8" --header "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" https://example.org/foo/bar '))
```

I haven't found a Python library to transform raw HTTP into such a `curl` command. However, this [Perl program](https://github.com/curl/h2c) does it.

Like this:

```
$ cat basic
GET /index.html HTTP/2
Host: example.com
Authorization: Basic aGVsbG86eW91Zm9vbA==
Accept: */*

$ ./h2c < basic
curl --http2 --header User-Agent: --user "hello:youfool" https://example.com/index.html
```

You could either call it from your python script, use a Python-Perl bridge or try to port it.

---

[Postman](https://www.postman.com/) also allows you to convert raw HTTP requests directly to python requests code, using its [Code snippet generator](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/). Although, it seems this can only be done via the GUI. It's also not Open-Source, so you can't access the code that does this transformation.

Answer (score 2):

I needed something that can generate a request and couldn't find it so ended up writing it in [gist](https://gist.github.com/cunla/c074179a587c0d012229ee8cc5c04a8c):

```
class RequestParser(object):
    def __parse_request_line(self, request_line):
        request_parts = request_line.split(' ')
        self.method = request_parts[0]
        self.url = request_parts[1]
        self.protocol = request_parts[2] if len(request_parts) > 2 else DEFAULT_HTTP_VERSION

    def __init__(self, req_text):
        req_lines = req_text.split(CRLF)
        self.__parse_request_line(req_lines[0])
        ind = 1
        self.headers = dict()
        while ind < len(req_lines) and len(req_lines[ind]) > 0:
            colon_ind = req_lines[ind].find(':')
            header_key = req_lines[ind][:colon_ind]
            header_value = req_lines[ind][colon_ind + 1:]
            self.headers[header_key] = header_value
            ind += 1
        ind += 1
        self.data = req_lines[ind:] if ind < len(req_lines) else None
        self.body = CRLF.join(self.data)

    def __str__(self):
        headers = CRLF.join(f'{key}: {self.headers[key]}' for key in self.headers)
        return f'{self.method} {self.url} {self.protocol}{CRLF}' \
               f'{headers}{CRLF}{CRLF}{self.body}'

    def to_request(self):
        req = requests.Request(method=self.method,
                               url=self.url,
                               headers=self.headers,
                               data=self.data, )
        return req
```